# Matching criteria for the below scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image]
Refer to above image. I had tables Diagnoses,Services and PreventativeServices in which i have a common field named DxCode  in diagnosis and PreventativeServices. DxCode in PreventativeServices table is an optional field as it acts as a configuration table for us. Suppose DxCode = DiagnosisCode, I have following scenarios, based on image:

1. If we have DxCode in both services and diagnosis table then compare it on DxCode and resultant row should be output of the comparison. If found output will be 10060 else no row.
2. If we have DxCode = null or blank in PreventativeServices  then  again output will be 10060.
3. If we dont have rows in our Diagnosis table against RegistrationId = 247237 but we have a row in PreventativeServices with along with diagnosis code then again resultant will be no row, else
4. out put will be 10060

I had following query for the same:

```
SELECT [ServiceID] AS PreventativeServiceId,
       [CPTCode]
FROM   PreventativeService ps
       INNER JOIN [Services] s(NOLOCK)
               ON ps.CPTCode = s.ServiceCode
       LEFT JOIN Diagnoses dx(NOLOCK)
              ON dx.RegistrationID = s.RegistrationID
WHERE  s.RegistrationId = @RegistrationId
       AND ps.IsActive = 1
       AND @AdmitDate BETWEEN ps.StartDate AND Isnull(PS.EndDate, @AdmitDate)
       AND @Gender = Isnull(ps.Gender, @Gender)
       AND @Age BETWEEN Isnull(ps.AgeFrom, @Age) AND Isnull(ps.AgeTo, @Age)
       AND dx.DiagnosisCode = ( CASE
                                  WHEN Rtrim(Ltrim(ps.DiagnosisCode)) = '' THEN dx.DiagnosisCode
                                  ELSE ps.DiagnosisCode
                                END )
```

**NOTE**

DiagnosisCode in PreventativeServices will contain null and blank as well.

**Requirement**

```
dx.DiagnosisCode = ( CASE
                       WHEN Rtrim(Ltrim(ps.DiagnosisCode)) = '' THEN dx.DiagnosisCode
                       ELSE ps.DiagnosisCode
                     END )
```

is failing for scenario , when I have blank('') diagnosis in PreventativeServices and no row in Diagnosis table

Comment: Do you have the corresponding registrationId and Service code in services table and CPTCode in PreventativeService table?

Comment: Yes ServiceCode in services table equals CPTCode of preventative services and registration id in services equals registration id in diagnosis table. This is how the three tables are related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, This is because null=null always returns false. You can try using isnull function.

```
    isnull(dx.DiagnosisCode,' ') = (
    CASE 
        WHEN rtrim(ltrim(ps.DiagnosisCode)) = ''
            THEN isnull(dx.DiagnosisCode,' ')
        ELSE ps.DiagnosisCode
        END
    )
```